# Can I create a byte[] straight from a folder?

Tags: java, zip, arrays, directory

A web Service expects a `byte[]` coming from a zip file.

I have some files in a folder that I zip with Java and then I get the `byte[]` from this zip file.

Is this necessary or can I create the `byte[]` straight from the folder?

Comment: Is the web Service expecting a zip with multiple files in it?  If so I think you can add the files to a `ZipStream` and send this to the web service without writing to disk (if they are not too big for memory).

Comment: @hack_on, the WS expects a Base64Binary from a byte[]. In an admin GUI console where the WS is used it lets you upload a zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would allow you to do what you want without writing as long as the files are not going to be very big.

```
String[] sourceFiles = { "C:/file1", "C:/file2" };

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.length; i++)
{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(sourceFiles[i]);
    zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(sourceFiles[i]));

    int length;
    while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    zout.closeEntry();
    fin.close();
}

zout.close();

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @hack_on, that looks like what I was searching for. The ByteAarayOutputStream class is the quid of the question and what I didn't know about. I'll try that out.

Comment: Finally it did not work. On the stack of exceptions it says something about an error from the service trying to unzip, so I guess it does need it to be zipped. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @eskalera the code above _does_ zip the files. Maybe you could put the stack trace in your question and someone will figure out what else is wrong?

Comment: not sured what I've done but I've tried again today and it works now. So your code was right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**A folder** is a collection of files. It **is a container**. It does not have a **byte** stream to get in the first place.

On the other hand, **a ZIP** (or any archive) **is a file**. The **information** about the different files **is stored within the ZIP file** itself

However, you can iterate through the folder contents, cook up a byte array and then use it (you are doing that anyways while creating the ZIP).

Comment: Would the cooked bytearray be the same as the one out of the zip file? If that's the case, with that approach I would avoid creating a file on disk.

Comment: Probably not. A ZIP file will contain its own information within itself. Plus the metadata about the files that it contains, and then the actual file data (compressed). 

On the other hand, with iteration, you are working with only the files themselves. The overhead of the "ZIP information" is not there.

Comment: @Visruth :: Thanks for removing the signature. Force of habit. My apologize.